# How to tell `hg update` that it can delete any new files in my working dir?

Tags: mercurial

- I `clone` a repo to c:\mycopy
- I create new files in my working dir

How can I tell `hg update` to delete any new files in my working dir? I don't want it to delete files that are in the ignored file patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [purge extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension).  It won't be update doing it, but you can purge after updating.

Answer (score 2):

[Danger, Will Robinson! Danger! Danger!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger,_Will_Robinson)

I *strongly* recommend you do not even try to do this. Here's a User Story:

It was a dark and stormy night. Rain and hail beats against the window, sounding like heavy weapons fire echoing through time from some long-forgotten battle fought off the shoulder of Orion. The programmer is under incredible stress, trying to complete the last critical piece of the code that will Save Humanity. *Suddenly* he knows he has it! He grabs a quick update and then does a commit! ... But he forgot to first do `hg add whatever` to add the files to his repository and his magic cleanup script instantly destroys the code, never to be reclaimed again.

Humanity is lost ... *LOST!*

and all because of an auto-cleanup script.

YMMV.

Comment: Do not even try to use hg? This is a fatal flaw if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

This script will produce a list of unknown (untracked but not ignored) files and remove them.  Run without the `xargs` part to preview which files will be deleted:

```
hg status -un | xargs rm
```

Comment: Too bad this does work on Windows. But the -un is still god to know.